# Quarkus 1.5.2.Final: Why when using maven compile dependencies only a part of the artifact are included in the final JAR?

Tags: maven, dependency-management, quarkus

In a Quarkus microservice I have the following dependency:

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>fr.simplex-software.quarkus</groupId>
  <artifactId>send-money-data</artifactId>
</dependency>
```

The fr.simplex-software.quarkus:send-money-data:jar artifact has the following structure:

[image: Structure of send-money-data]

This structure is found while looking inside its JAR. However, after building the micro-service including this same JAR as a dependency, looking in the micros-service JAR, I see that:

```
 ...
 0 Mon Jul 27 16:38:03 CEST 2020 fr/
 0 Mon Jul 27 16:38:03 CEST 2020 fr/simplex_software/
 0 Mon Jul 27 16:38:03 CEST 2020 fr/simplex_software/eip/
 0 Mon Jul 27 16:38:03 CEST 2020 fr/simplex_software/eip/money_transfer/
 0 Mon Jul 27 16:38:03 CEST 2020 fr/simplex_software/eip/money_transfer/model/
 0 Mon Jul 27 16:38:03 CEST 2020 fr/simplex_software/eip/money_transfer/model/repositories/
 14366 Mon Jul 27 16:38:03 CEST 2020 fr/simplex_software/eip/money_transfer/model/repositories/MoneyTransferRepository.class
 14089 Mon Jul 27 16:38:03 CEST 2020 fr/simplex_software/eip/money_transfer/model/repositories/BankRepository.class
 0 Mon Jul 27 16:38:03 CEST 2020 fr/simplex_software/eip/money_transfer/model/jpa/
  4001 Mon Jul 27 16:38:03 CEST 2020 fr/simplex_software/eip/money_transfer/model/jpa/SourceBankAccountEntity.class
  8436 Mon Jul 27 16:38:03 CEST 2020 fr/simplex_software/eip/money_transfer/model/jpa/MoneyTransferEntity.class
  4001 Mon Jul 27 16:38:03 CEST 2020 fr/simplex_software/eip/money_transfer/model/jpa/TargetBankAccountEntity.class
 11861 Mon Jul 27 16:38:03 CEST 2020 fr/simplex_software/eip/money_transfer/model/jpa/BankAddressEntity.class
  8143 Mon Jul 27 16:38:03 CEST 2020 fr/simplex_software/eip/money_transfer/model/jpa/BankEntity.class
  ...
```

As you can see, only the sub-packages **jpa** and **repositories** of the **model** package are included, but not the sub-packages **dto** and **mapping** ! Why is that and how can I work around that ? I've tried to hack with the jandex-maven-plugin, even if I don't really understand what is supposed to do, but nothing changed.

Many thanks in advance for any help.

Comment: Are you trying to build an uberjar and the files are not included in the uberjar? Are you sure you don't have split packages by any chance?

Comment: No, that's not an uberjar, just a normal jar. And if by "split packages" you mean the same package in two or more artifacts, then yes, I'm sure.

Comment: Just to avoid any possible confusion, the "normal jar" I'm talking about here is an executable one (having "-runer" at the end of its name).

Comment: If you're not using an uberjar, I would say your original library jar should be copied in `target/lib/` and present in the classpath. Do you have a real issue or an exception?

Comment: No, the dependencies other then the quarkus ones don't appear in lib and this is the issue.

Comment: They should if you're not building an uberjar. If you can reproduce this issue with a simple reproducer not including private classes, please create an issue in our GitHub tracker with the reproducer.

Comment: I know it should but it doesn't. Once again: I'm not building an uberjar but a stand-alone, executable (to be executed with java -jar ...). I'm not doing any fancy thing. I have an utility project which is a separated artifact as a simple jar (not uber, not stand-alone, just a jar). This utility project should be used by several micro-services. Please don't tell me that micro-services aren't supposed to include anything and to be completely independent because it doesn't exist such a thing like completely independent components.

Comment: And I can't copy/paste the utility in all its consumers. Now, when I run one of these micro-services supposed to use the utility, I get CNFE at the runtime. And as a matter of fact, the mentioned classes aren't in the resulting JAR, nor in the lib directory. I'm not using neither extensions, nor jandex 'cause I don't understand what they are supposed to do. Not sure to have more time to waste on that in order to create a reproducer but I think that these explanations should be largely enough to understand what I'm talking about.